# changing the files in my git commit after performing a Git Push Command

Tags: git, git-push

so we make use of GitLab and so I had to send out a mergereq request. It was during the mergereq I realised that I had done a git commit of additional files " temporary and unrequired "; Is there a way of undoing this ? I have tried

> git commit --amend

But this changes only the commit message whereas I need to remove the unnecessary files as well.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `git commit --amend` *does* allow you to add new modifications to the last commit. The case in which it only updates the commit message is when you use the `-m` parameter.

But rather than trying to `rm` unwanted files from the index, I'd suggest doing the following from your local branch* :

```
# undo last commit while keeping changes in the working tree
git reset HEAD^

# redo the adding part without the unwanted files
git add file1 file2 file3

# commit and push
git commit -m "message"
git push --force origin HEAD
```

Now just refresh your PR page, it will update itself, replacing the faulty commit with the new one.

*(* assuming this is your feature branch, on which you can force-push without disrupting someone else's work. Correct me if I'm wrong here)*